# Only applying a Spring Cloud Gateway filter on some responses

Tags: kotlin, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

I have a Spring Cloud Gateway service sitting in front of a number of backend services but currently it does not log very much. I wanted to log responses from backend services whenever they return unexpected response status codes but I've hit on the following problem.

I can log the response body for requests using a modifyResponseBody filter and a RewriteFunction like so:

```
    .route("test") { r ->
        r.path("/httpbin/**")
            .filters { f ->
                f.modifyResponseBody(String::class.java, String::class.java){ exchange, string ->
                    if(e.response.statusCode.is2xxSuccessful)println("Server error")
                    Mono.just(string)
                }
            }.uri("http://httpbin.org")
    }
```

My issue with this method is that I'm parsing the response ByteArray to a String on every response, with the overhead that implies, even though I'm just using the body string on a small subset of those responses.

I've tried instead to implement a custom filter like so:

```
    .route("test2") {r ->
        r.path("/httpbin2/**")
            .filters { f ->
                f.filter(LogUnexpectedResponseFilter()
                     .apply(LogUnexpectedResponseFilter.Config(listOf(HttpStatus.OK))))
            }.uri("http://httpbin.org")
    }
```

```
class LogUnexpectedResponseFilter : AbstractGatewayFilterFactory<LogUnexpectedResponseFilter.Config>() {

    val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this::class.java)

    override fun apply(config: Config?): GatewayFilter {

        return GatewayFilter { exchange, chain ->
            logger.info("running custom filter")

            if (config?.errors!!.contains(exchange.response.statusCode)){
                return@GatewayFilter ModifyResponseBodyGatewayFilterFactory().apply(ModifyResponseBodyGatewayFilterFactory.Config()
                        .setInClass(String::class.java)
                        .setOutClass(String::class.java)
                        .setRewriteFunction(String::class.java, String::class.java) { _, body ->
                            logger.error(body)
                            Mono.just(body)
                        }).filter(exchange, chain)

            } else {
                chain.filter(exchange)
            }

        }

    }

    data class Config(val errors: List<HttpStatus>)

}
```

What this is *supposed* to do is simply let the request pass through on most requests but apply the log filter on those that I have configured it to (although in this example I'm having it log on 200 status responses).

What I'm seeing when I debug is that it correctly applies the right filter but the RewriteFunction inside it isn't being run at all. What am I missing?

Comment: Did you know netty can log everything already? No need for a filter.

Comment: @spencergibb Are you referring to `-Dreactor.netty.http.server.accessLogEnabled=true`? As far as I can tell this isn't going to give me the body of the response and it also isn't going to let me configure different response status codes to log for different routes.

Comment: Are you sure it's correctly applying the filter? I had a similar filter to that and the Config wasn't cast correctly because I was missing a call to the base constructor where I specified the Config I'm going to use. Something like this:

constructor(): super(Config::class.java)